# using eclipse after dreamweaver cs5.5 build mobile app

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator, jquery-mobile, dreamweaver

If someone has some experience in building an app from dreamweaver cs5.5, were you able to put import it in eclipse?

It seems like its not able to get any files from it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still havn't figured it out, but I'm just using eclipse to build all my mobile apps now, from scratch.